# php unable to add rand() move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php

I have been trying to upload a file with `move_uploaded_file` for a while now and for some reason something strange happens. Here is my code that I'm using right now:

```
$rand = rand();
$_SESSION['rand'] = $rand;

$uploaddir = "csv/";  
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_SESSION['rand'] . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$_SESSION['filenaam'] = $_SESSION['rand'].$_FILES['file']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
    {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "Upload failed";
    }
```

When I try to upload this `$uploadfile` it goes well and I can find it in the csv map, yet there are 2 problems. The 1st one is that even though the file is uploaded I always get the `else respond(echo "Upload failed outlook";)`. The 2nd one is that the name of the file that I'm trying to save in the `$_SESSION['filenaam']` is way different, for some reason the rand function is being reused instead of the results of the 1st one.

Can someone help me out with this problem?

Comment: Everytime the script is run, the value in $_SESSION['rand'] will change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the second problem you can do that:

Less than PHP5.2:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['rand'])) { 
    rand();
}
```

More than PHP5.3

```
$_SESSION['rand'] = ($_SESSION['rand']) ?: rand() ;
```

Comment: How does this one work ? cause im trying to edit it cause it gives me a error at the ?:

Comment: which php version are you using?

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.17, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' is what I get when I use your code instead

Comment: Great thanks, do you also by any chance know how to comes that the file is being uploaded by the move_uploaded_file yet continues with the else ?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be better for you to do this instead of random to use a uniqid(); instead each time you call the rand() function a different value is generated.

Comment: with the uniqid() you are generating every time another value too.

Comment: Is it so?? But it doesn't seem to change each time....At least for me. If it doesn't work i explained the guy's solution below for you :)